# Java - Factory Method that returns generic Base type

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to genericize a factory method that returns
a generic Base class.  It works, but I'm getting the
"BaseClass is a raw type..." warning.

I've read through the Java docs on Generic methods,
but I'm still not quite getting how to accomplish this.

Here's some code:

Class #1

```
//base abstract class
public abstract class BaseFormatter<T>
{
    public abstract String formatValue(T value);
}
```

Class #2

```
//two implementations of concrete classes
public class FooFormatter extends BaseFormatter<Integer>
{
    @Override
    public String formatValue(Integer value)
    {
        //return a formatted String
    }
}
```

Class #3

```
public class BarFormatter extends BaseFormatter<String>
{
    @Override
    public String formatValue(String value)
    {
        //return a formatted String
    }
}
```

Factory Method in a separate class

```
public static BaseFormatter getFormatter(Integer unrelatedInteger)
{
    if (FOO_FORMATTER.equals(unrelatedInteger))
        return new FooFormatter();
    else if (BAR_FORMATTER.equals(unrelatedInteger))
        return new BarFormatter();
    //else...
}
```

Call to the Factory Method from elsewhere in the code

```
BaseFormatter<Integer> formatter = getFormatter(someInteger);
formatter.formatValue(myIntegerToFormat);
```

The problem is the getFormatter() method warns that BaseFormatter is
a raw type, which it is.  I've tried various things like BaseFormatter
et al.  I, of course, want the return type to be generic, as in the declared
BaseFormatter in the calling method.

Note that the formatter type is not based on class type.  e.g. not all Integer
values are formatted with a FooFormatter.  There are two or three different
ways an Integer (or String, or List) can be formatted.  That's what the
param unrelatedInteger is for.

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: The simple answer: the Java type system cannot express the constraint you want safely. This means you can't get rid of the warning for this cast.

Answer (score 0):

If getFormatter is defined in BaseFormatter, then use:

```
public static BaseFormatter<T> getFormatter(Integer unrelatedInteger)
```

If getFormatter is defined in another class than BaseFormatter, then use:

```
public static BaseFormatter<?> getFormatter(Integer unrelatedInteger)
```

Comment: If I do BaseFormatter<T>, I have to do it like this: public static <T> BaseFormatter<T> getFormatter(Integer converter).  I can't do this because return new FooFormatter() causes an error.  Cannot convert from FooFormatter to BaseFormatter<T>, so this won't work.

Comment: I read your update.  Here's the problem:  getFormatter is defined in another class.  If I return a BaseFormatter of type unknown (BaseFormatter<?>), this method is happy.  But in the calling method, I can't do BaseFormatter<Integer> formatter = getFormatter(someInteger);  I get a type mismatch error.  If I change that to BaseFormatter<?> formatter = getFormatter(someInteger); then I can't pass in an Integer because the type is unknown, not an Integer.

Comment: @TedJones Can you please edit your question by posting each class as it is (alone) not as you did (combined) because it's hard to see who's who and how who is calling who

Answer (score 0):

You're actuaaly saying that there's no connection between the typed parameter of `BaseFormatter` and the `unrelatedInteger` that is passed as argument to the `getFormatter` method.

I get some other warning:

```
Uncehcked Assignment: BaseFormatter to BaseFormatter<Integer>
```

This warning is worse than the one you indicated. It warns that this user code might try to insert a `BaseFormatter<String>` into `BaseFormatter<Integer>`, something that will be noticed only when fails in runtime... Consider a user accidentally uses you factory method like such:

```
BaseFormatter<Integer> myUnsafeFormatter =
        FormatterFactory.getFormatter(unrelatedIntegerForBarFormatter);
```

The compiler cannot relate the `unrelatedInteger` with the parameterized type of the returned `BaseFormatter`.

Alternitavely, I'd let the user explicitly use the concrete formatter constructors. Any common code shared by all formatters could be put into `FormatterUtils` class (just don't let that utils class to grow to much...).

Answer (score 0):

Some type systems in academic languages can express a so-called dependent sum.  Java certainly cannot; so what, sensibly, could be the type of the object returned by the getFormatter method?  The best we can do is `BaseFormatter< ? extends Object >`, or `BaseFormatter< ? >` for short, as `Integer` and  `String` have only `Object` in common.

I think the original post begs the question, why must we use an integer to decide what formatter to return, and if the type of formatter would not be known by the caller, why would the caller need a stronger variable type than `BaseFormatter< ? >`?

Comment: Well, technically, it doesn't need anything more than BaseFormatter<?>.  The problem is it's using the BaseFormatter as an interface of sorts, calling the same format() method with the appropriate data type.  Before it was taking Object and casting it the correct type.  This, of course, was a problem because it's open to class cast exception.  When genericizing this, it was reasonable to force the datatype on the format(arg) method.  Since different formatters take different types, I'm forced to use T in the superclass.  The only other alternative I can think of is to  (continued next post)

Comment: replace BaseFormatter<Integer> formatter = getFormatter(someInteger);
with an if statement and instantiate the correct formatter.  It's called in several locations, so that's lame.  I put that code in one common location.  But to make FooFormatter and BarFormatter work the same (e.g. same method call, different argtype), it needs a superclass with an abstract method both must implement.  One other solution I'm considering is having a CommonFormatter and overloading format(), so I can do cf.format(unrelatedInteger, myIntToFormat, cf.format(unrelatedInteger, myStrToFormat). (continued next post)

Comment: since I can have several different formats (there are more than 2, but I kept it at 2 for this example), each of those methods will have a series of if statements.  e.g. `if (FOO_FORMATTER.equals(unrelatedInteger))
        //do foo formatting;
    else if (BAR_FORMATTER.equals(unrelatedInteger))
        //do bar formatting`  I don't like that at all.  I'm open to any suggestions anybody has.